# Step by Step explanation of derivative of a matrix

Tags: calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm working on a proof that requires me to simplify the derivative of a positive definite matrix.  I'm relatively new to matrix calculus so I have been searching the internet for a good example.  I haven't been able to find a good explanation though or step by step example of finding the derivative of a matrix.

For example, suppose I have a matrix

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}a + x&c\\c&b + x\end{array}\right) $$

and I wanted to take the derivative of it with respect to x with scalars a,b,c.  How would I go about this and where would I start?

Thanks in advance

Edit

intuitively,

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}a + x&c\\c&b + x\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a &c\\c&b\end{array}\right) + \left(\begin{array}{cc}x&0\\0&x\end{array}\right)
$$
so
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \left(\begin{array}{cc}a + x& c\\c&b + x\end{array}\right) &= \frac{d}{dx} \left(\begin{array}{cc}a&c\\c&b\end{array}\right) + \frac{d}{dx} \left(\begin{array}{cc}x&0\\0&x\end{array}\right) \\
&= 0 + \frac{d}{dx}  \big(\begin{array}{cc}x\hat{\imath} + x\hat{\jmath}\end{array}\big) \\
&= \big(\begin{array}{cc}\hat{\imath} + \hat{\jmath}\end{array}\big) \\
&= \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What is $\frac{dx}{df}$?  Do mean to differentiate the matrix *with respect to* $x$?  In that case, you write the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ in front of the expression that you want the derivative of.

Comment: Yes sorry typo :). Writing what I'm thinking and copy and pasting.

Comment: For your present purposes, the $2 \times 2$ matrix is just an alternative way to present an array of $4$ expressions.  The (likely) more familiar way is to think of a $4$-tuple.  Suppose that you had the function $F: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^4$, defined by $F(x) = \left( a + x, c, c, b + x \right)$.  Would you know how to differentiate $F$ with respect to $x$?  That is, can you find $\frac{dF}{dx}$?

Comment: Isn't that what I have done in my attempt?

Comment: Looks good to me. What you are saying is that the change in your matrix when you modify $x$ by $\Delta x$ is $\Delta x I$, which it is.

Comment: @user2736423 Your original result is correct. You differentiate a family of matrices depending on a parameter x by differentiating each component separately, see the analogy from Sammy Black's comment.